# How do i shrink my link menu

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, menu

I need help with some menu items on my site. The thing is, i think i have solved this problem in the past but i have forgotten about how i went about it. 
I have about 7 menu links that i floated and if my browser is fully maximized, it looks fine as it covers the entire with but when the browser is restored to a smaller size, it pushes some of the links to the bottom. Below is the html and css.

```
 #menu  a
 {
 float:left;        
 padding:16px 20px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#000;
 display:block; 
 border-right:1px solid #646464;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:90%;
 }

 <div id="menu">
 <a href="">Home</a>
 <a href="">About us</a>
 <a href="">Services</a>
 <a href="">Products</a>
 <a href="">Portfolio</a>
 <a href="">Frequently Asked Question</a>
 <a href="">Contact us</a>
 </div>
```

The thing is, i want it in such a way that when the width of the browser is smaller or if browser size is reduced, it should reduce the size of the font and probably reduce the size of the padding for each link.

Comment: So if the browser's window gets _very_ small, your links will be almost invisible?

Comment: Yes. You sould try media queries for small device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is, that you got a fixed value for the padding... so if the browser is smaller than the comulative padding pixels... it won't fit...

a possible solution would be, to remove the horizontal padding and use a relative width value...

like the following:

```css
#menu  a{
 float:left;        
 padding:16px 0;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#000;
 display:block; 
 border-right:1px solid #646464;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:90%;
 width:14%
 }
```

```html
 <div id="menu">
 <a href="">Home</a>
 <a href="">About us</a>
 <a href="">Services</a>
 <a href="">Products</a>
 <a href="">Portfolio</a>
 <a href="">Frequently Asked Question</a>
 <a href="">Contact us</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you re-sized it ? I re-sized my browser and it was distorted.  I think it is better to use media screen.Keeping the menu inline in desktop and aligning vertical in mobile is a good idea.

Comment: glad i could help :) by the way: you can accept the answer by clicking on the "check" icon under the number (in this case 0) next to my post ;)